# oauth2 - how was user identified before OIDC?

Tags: oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, openid-connect

Im a bit confused about oauth2 and OIDC.

So supposedly with OIDC we now get the `id_token` which uniquely identifies the user in the same oauth2 flow.
But my understanding is - oauth 2 came out earlier than OIDC and OIDC support is not universal even at this point.

So how do current APIs that use oauth2 (without OIDC) work?
Let's say there is a mobile app that needs to use some API.
Is the idea that after mobile app get's oauth2 access token -> they always have to hit some endpoint like `/me` using that access token which will then provide user id information? and thus the api has to track which access tokens have been given to each particular user?

Sry this question comes out like request for some trivia info - but Im really new to oauth2 & OIDC and just trying to understand and make sure im not missing anything....

Answer (score 1):

[OAuth 2.0 NOT an Authentication protocol.](http://ldapwiki.com/wiki/OAuth%202.0%20NOT%20an%20Authentication%20protocol)
OAuth 2.0 is more of a delegation protocol where the Resource Owner delegates certain permissions to a OAuth Client.

OIDC is an Authentication protocol built on top of OAuth 2.0.

OAuth 2.0 should be used where a user (Resource Owner) is delegating permissions to an Application (OAuth Client) to perform some action.

OIDC should be used where an an Application (OAuth Client) needs to some "Level of Assurance" that the user (Resource Owner) is who he says he is.

The Authentication is done by a Third-Party (Authorization Server). The id_token allows the Client to access information about the user that the Authorization Server knows about (and hopefully has performed some verification).

Answer (score 0):

As jwilleke answered it, OAuth 2.0 is for authorization. OpenID Connect (OIDC) is built on OAuth 2.0 adds Authentication layer.

Basically, OAuth 2.0 delegate the client application to access a protected endpoint on-behalf of the resource owner. In simple words, end user authorise the application access a resource/service. In this process, application does not receive any detail about the end user so it cannot authenticate/detect(In OIDC, application receive the id token, which is self-sufficient enough to authenticate the end-user) end user.

> **Q :** Is the idea that after mobile app get's oauth2 access token -> they always have to hit some endpoint like /me using that access token which will then provide user id information? and thus the api has to track which access tokens have been given to each particular user?

From OAuth 2.0 perspective, there is no end user information sharing. But the token issuing identity provider understand the tokens it issued. Internally it can map end user details, permissions and anything it requires to process it. With that, when the API (resource server) receive the access token, it can validate the token. Note that resource server and authorization could be the same or different. And these are implementation specific details.  Alternatively one could use token introspection as defined in [rfc7662](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7662) to detect validity of issues access tokens.

**Example scenario**

You have mobile app A. And it have the ability to use a service B (protected by Access tokens) which is exposed by service provider G. Assume there is a user Alex who have already registered at SP G so have access to service B and uses app A. And SP G have OAuth 2.0 implemented so service B accepts access tokens issued by SP G.

User Alex use App A and there is a functionality in the App A which need to consume service B. App A require authorisation from Alex to consume service B on-behalf of him/her. In doing so, there will be a user login process and at the end SP G issue access token to App A. Does it convey identity of Alex ? No it does not. But App A can now consume service B using access token it received. Service B fully understand and can validate access tokens issues by SP G. IMO This is OAuth 2.0 in nutshell.

p.s - Substitute known services like Google calendar, Google identity and your android app so that it make more sense.